# Disk space is not freed up when deleting files on a hard drive

Tags: debian, rsync, disk-usage, storage, delete

I'm trying to sync a hard drive to another one as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1824760/385861).

The problem was that it finished with errors because it reached "No space left on device" and Grsync does not backup root-owned files.

I then ran the rsync command of Grsync in the console as also described above. The command is `sudo rsync -r -t -p -o -g --delete -l -s disk1 disk2`

It had many "skipping non-regular file" errors but that is a separate problem (it should backup 100.0%) and eventually also got a No space left on device error despite that there are many GBs of disk space free on disk1. `sudo lsof | grep {diskname}` shows disk2 is not used by anything.

The problem I have that when I delete something on disk2 to free disk space to allow for another sync, it doesn't show that more disk space is available in the Dolphin file browser or when entering `lsblk -f` or `df` (the latter still shows 0 in the column Available).

I deleted it by right clicking the file in Dolphin and choosing delete. I also tried "Move to Trash" but there is only the backed up Trash folder (I can't exclude it with Grsync) but no Trash folder at the root directory of the drive.

**How to actually delete the files and free up the disk space** or make it show the actually available disk space if it's just displaying that wrong? I'm using Debian with KDE.

---

**Unnecessary details to skip:**

I thought logging out and back in to restart the session would solve this but it didn't and it still shows 0 bytes of disk space free. `rm filename` does not free up disk space either. As requested the output of `lsof | grep deleted` is below; many of those messages showed many times and I left out some columns and replaced Ids:

```
pulseaudi ... /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
ksmserver ... /home/username/.cache/ksycoca5_{lang}_{id} (deleted)
plasmashe ... /home/username/.cache/ksycoca5_{lang}_{id} (deleted)
plasmashe ... /home/username/.cache/appstream/appcache-{id}.mdb (deleted)
vorta ... /usr/share/mime/mime.cache (deleted)
{texteditor} ... /home/username/.cache/ksycoca5_{lang}_{id} (deleted)
konsole ... /home/username/.cache/konsole/#{number} (deleted)
```

after restarting the session there is an additional .lock file open by a printer program, the two pulseaudi, and the konsole ones but nothing else. I still can't free up disk space if `lsblk -f` and Dolphin display the correct available space.

I also tried `sudo lsof | grep deleted | grep mountname` and it does not give any output. mountname is part of the dir since I mounted it there (`sudo lsof | grep mountname1` works for files open that are on the other drive and even `sudo lsof | grep mountname` does not show anything).

Comment: By diskname, do you mean the directory to which your are trying to `rsync` the data (disk2) or the name of an actual disk?

Comment: *I deleted it by right clicking the file in Dolphin and choosing delete.*  GUI file applications often don't remove files, instead moving them to a 'trashcan' where they can be recovered.  What happens when you pick a file that's large enough to be noticed and use `rm filename` to delete the file?

Comment: You're grepping wrong. `lsof` shows files (file descriptors to be more correct) and sockets, not partitions.

Comment: @NasirRiley The directory (top folder of the mounted encrypted disk). @SottoVoce I also wrote that there is a separate entry for moving the item to a trashcan. Delete should remove it directly. Using `rm` to delete also doesn't free diskspace. @Artem It should show all files in use. When I do that for another disk it shows me if for example a mp3 file from the disk is played. I tried `lsof +L1` and it shows `.cache` files and `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache`

Comment: Add the output of `lsof | grep deleted` to the question.

Comment: @NasirRiley I have added that.

Comment: Please show the actual `rsync` command you used. Please also include the output of `df -h`

Comment: @ChrisDavies The one I used after Grsync is above except that I added `sudo` in front of it; the command I ran using Grsync is `rsync -r -t -p -o -g --progress --delete -l -s ../dir1 ../dir2`. `df -h` still shows `0` in the column `Avail` and `100%` in `Use%`

Comment: Please add the information to your question so that everyone can easily see it. (With 4000+ points you should know by now that comments can be deleted or missed.)  Oh. and since you're using relative paths starting with `..` please show what directory you're in too. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: That info is already included and you shouldn't have asked in the first place since it's already there. And the .. was just a placeholder, it's an absolute dir not a relative.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm I'm trying to help you. There's clearly an issue that you can't resolve because otherwise you wouldn't have posted. I am happy to try and help you get it sorted but without the information I've asked for I cannot get a base-line starting point that would be obvious to me if I were standing alongside you at your computer